# Cannot Use Generic version of EventHandler in Monotouch properly

Tags: c#, generics, event-handling, mono, xamarin.ios

Here is the line of code...pretty simple and well-known for everyone...

```
public event EventHandler<TimeSpan> TimeExtended;
```

in Visual Studio (on windows I mean) it works as usual but in MonoTouch I can't use TimeSpan because it is not convertible to EventArgs and I can only use the types who derives from EventArgs. How can I use that this generic event handler in mono?

Thanks

Comment: Create a class that derives from `EventArgs` and has a property with type `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I did that and it worked but for some of my own classes who already derived from another object, I can't since in C# we can't derive from 2 objects.

Comment: That code won't work anywhere.  `EventHandler<T>` requires a type `T` which inherits from `EventArgs` and `TimeSpan` does not.

Comment: @jam40jeff well I see that it is working on windows

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected.  I checked the docs and I see that the .NET 4.5 framework removed this requirement (I had tried it in .NET 4.0 and it does not work).  @mikez 's suggestion is still the best way to go if possible.  For your classes already deriving from another object, once again make an `EventArgs` class which contains one property holding your object of your custom type.

Comment: I am thinking of having a custom generic event handler

Comment: @Peyman Why do you think you need to inherit from two classes?

Comment: I have a class called Player and it already derives from another class . and I can't do that for the Player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this event handler and I guess it is working.

```
public delegate void GEventHandler<T>(object sender, T args);
```

Answer (score 5):

It works in Visual Studio because you are using .Net 4.5 where the type constraint was dropped. Just define your own class inheriting from `EventArgs`. If you need additional data, then include it as well.

```
public class TimeExtendedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public TimeSpan TimeExtended { get; set; }
  public Player Player { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<TimeExtendedEventArgs> TimeExtended;
```

Comment: You are right...until mono supports .net 4.5 I need to use another way. something like you did here.